# you [adj] used as you [noun]

Tags: idiomatic-language

> Stop talking nonsense, you brainless!
>
> Stop talking nonsense, you idiot!

I remember that you can use adjective as noun, but I don't remember in what context though, so I was wondering if "you brainless" is correct.

Another example would be:

> Stop saying these stupid things, you unintelligent!

Which sounds even more weird and unidiomatic for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, adjectives aren't used as nouns in this situation, so you would have to use a noun in these phrases instead. In fact, I'd say in most contexts adjectives can't be used as nouns.

One context where adjectives can be used as nouns is using "the [adj]" as a plural noun meaning "all who are [adj]":

> Only the brainless talk such nonsense.

This is a somewhat poetic usage.

Sometimes people will use adjectives as nouns in a slightly informal way to list or compare items:

> What color beads do you have?

> I have two greens and a blue.